# ASP.NET Core 3.1 application does not terminate process after Program.Main finishes running

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have a rather large ASP.NET Core application running in an IIS application pool with overlapped recycling. I have set `IHostApplicationLifetime` handlers and I see that it is hitting all of the lifecycle methods as well as the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` handler that I've set. When I request a recycle, here's what happens:

1. `ApplicationStopping` is hit
2. `ApplicationStopped` is hit
3. Dependencies configured in `Startup` are disposed
4. Breakpoint after `webHost.Run()` in `Program.cs` is hit (this is the last line of the `Main` method of the program)
5. `ProcessExit` handler is run

At this point I would expect `w3wp` to be dead. But no, it lingers around for quite a while after, and continues to take a lot of memory. I also can view it in Process Explorer and I see it still has a bit of activity.

[image: zombie w3wp]

I guess the obvious things to look for are things that need to be disposed, but I don't know how to look for these. How can I figure out why `w3wp` will not go away for such a long time / what is keeping it around?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, hit the ProcessExit handler means the asp.net core application has been down, not the w3wp.exe.

The w3wp.exe is managed by IIS not the websites. The IIS will check the w3wp.exe is free or not(handing  request). If there is no request coming in about 20 minutes(by default). Then the IIS will stop the w3wp.exe.

The IIS console manager contains the idle timeout value. If you want to shut down the w3wp.exe as soon as possible. I suggest you could reduce the value to 1 which means if there is no request coming in 1 minutes, it will stop the w3wp.exe.

More details about how to set it, you could refer to below steps:

1. Open the IIS management console and find the application pool

[image]

2.Click the advanced setting and modify idle time-out

[image]